# Coherence between two signals at a particular frequency is less than one, yet the corresponding frequency components differ by a scalar multiple

Tags: frequency-spectrum, coherence

I'm sampling from the functions $x(t)=\cos(2\pi f_0t)$ and $y(t)=\cos(2\pi f_0t^{1.005})$, for one second, where $f_0=300$ and my sampling rate is
$f_s=1000$. ($N=1000$).

A plot of the coherence between the signal samples, $x$ and $y$ is shown below, which indicates a maximum coherence of 0.74
bin $m=299$, which is what I would expect.

[image]

My signal samples for $x$ can be viewed as a vector, $\vec{x}$ in $\mathbb{R}^{1000}$ and can be expressed as a linear combination of the
columns of the Fourier matrix
$W=\begin{bmatrix} \vec{w}_0 & \vec{w}_1 & \vec{w}_2 & \cdots & \vec{w}_{N-1} \end{bmatrix}$, whose columns are pairwise orthogonal and have squared-norms
equal to $N$:

\begin{equation*}
\vec{x}=\overline{\frac{\vec{x} \bullet \vec{w}_0}{N} }\cdot \vec{w}_0+ \overline{\frac{\vec{x} \bullet \vec{w}_1}{N} }\cdot \vec{w}_1+ \cdots+ 
\overline{\frac{\vec{x} \bullet \vec{w}_{N-1}}{N}} \cdot \vec{w}_{N-1}.
\end{equation*}

A similar formula exists for the signal samples for $y$. In linear algebra language, I have interpreted the coherence between $x$ and $y$ at bin $m$ to represent the degree to which there
exists a linear relationship between the orthogonal projections $\displaystyle \overline{\frac{\vec{x} \bullet \vec{w}_m}{N} }\cdot \vec{w}_m$ and
$\displaystyle \overline{\frac{\vec{y} \bullet \vec{w}_m}{N} }\cdot \vec{w}_m$. In this case, when I calculated the ratios of corresponding pairs of complex
numbers in these projection vectors, they are constant, as demonstrated below, which is not what I would expect since the coherence is significantly less than one.
I'm seeking guidance regarding where my misconception lies. (I'm trying to think of coherence not in terms of ratios of power spectral densities but
in terms of linear algebra, ideas which are accessible to my undergraduate students.)

```
dt = .001
t = np.arange(0, 1, dt)
N=len(t)
fs=int(1/dt)

x=np.cos(2 * np.pi * f0 * t)
y=np.cos(2 * np.pi * f0 * t**(1.005))

def DFT_matrix(N):
    i, j = np.meshgrid(np.arange(N), np.arange(N))
    omega = np.exp( - 2 * np.pi * 1J / N )
    W = np.power( omega, i * j )
    return W

W=DFT_matrix(N)
m=299
w_m=W[:,m]

x_m=np.dot(x,w_m )*w_m/N
y_m=np.dot(y,w_m)*w_m/N
ratios=np.divide(x_m,y_m)
print(ratios[90:100])

[-1.38423982+1.00824419j -1.38423982+1.00824419j -1.38423982+1.00824419j
 -1.38423982+1.00824419j -1.38423982+1.00824419j -1.38423982+1.00824419j
 -1.38423982+1.00824419j -1.38423982+1.00824419j -1.38423982+1.00824419j
 -1.38423982+1.00824419j]
```

Comment: How did you calculate the coherence, can you share the code?

Comment: I used ```f,Coh_xy=coherence(x,y,fs=fs,nfft=len(x))```, where ```coherence``` was imported from ```scipy.signal```. Perhaps my misunderstanding centers on how I'm thinking of coherence in the first place?